# Linear Maps and confusion over a definition

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I have the following definition of a linear map (note $V$ and $W$ are vector spaces over a field $F$)

A linear map $T$ from $V$ to $W$ is a function that satisfies the following two conditions.

1. additivity: $T(v+u)=Tu+Tv$ for all $u,v \in V$
2. homogeneity: $T(av)=a(Tv)$ for all $a \in F$ and for all $v \in V$

Let $\mathcal{L}(U,V)$ denote the set of all linear maps from a vector space $U$ to $V$.

A product between two linear maps is then defined.

If $T \in \mathcal{L}(U,V)$ and $S \in \mathcal{L}(V,W)$ then define $ST \in \mathcal{L}(U,W)$ such that $ST(v)=S(Tv)$ this definition comes with a disclaimer that this product can only be defined when $T$ maps into the domain of $S$.

This is where i'm confused. Surely the domain of $S$ is $V$? So if $T$ is a linear map from $U$ to $V$ how could it not map into the domain of $S$? Surely if $S \in \mathcal{L}(V,W)$ then by definition it is a function from $V$ to $W$ in which case it's domain is $V$? Is there something i'm missing? I'd be grateful for any clarification. Or any examples showing this isn't always the case. Any help is much appreciated thanks!

Comment: You've already written $S \in \mathcal{L}(V,W)$, indicating that the domain is $V$. Did you not mean to do so? Right now this question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that we might have two linear maps $T\in \mathcal{L}(U,V)$ and $S\in \mathcal{L}(X,Y)$ so that $U,V,X,$ and $Y$ are distinct linear spaces. Then, there is no obvious way to compose $S$ with $T$ or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematically speaking, the disclaimer is not neccesary. Saying that $T\in \mathcal L(U,V)$ and $S\in\mathcal L(V,W)$ is enough.

However, it is very important that if $T\in \mathcal L(U, V_1)$ and $S\in\mathcal L(V_2, W)$, then $ST$ is only defined if $V_1=V_2$.

It is sometimes good for a textbook to say something that is mathematically redundant, because it may not be redundant from the point of understanding what that means.

Comment: Ahh ok i thought perhaps that's what they were eluding too that makse sense, thanks!